# document.getElementById is not returning any value

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am playing around with TypeScript and am trying to create a script that will fetch the HTML values of a div with class and id.

However, I am able to get the result for a class but I cannot fetch the result using `getElementById`.

The html looks as following:

```
<button (click)="selectDiv()">select div</button>

   <div class="container"  id="main-wrapper">   
<p>
 Fetch me
</p>
</div>
```

And the `explore.ts` file

```
selectDiv() {
     //create a new HTMLElement from nativeElement
    var hElement: HTMLElement = this.elRef.nativeElement;

    //now you can simply get your elements with their class name
   var allDivs = hElement.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];

   var getSection = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById["main-wrapper"].innerHTML;

    console.log(allDivs);
    console.log(getSection); // returning nothing
  }
```

`getsection` is giving me an error as follows:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Comment: The preferred way in Angular to obtain an element--if you really need to, which is actually a rare case--is to use `ViewChild` instead of DOM interfaces such as `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementById`. There are good reasons for this, which are too detailed to go into here.

Comment: I am trying to make a simple HTML editor using angular2. I am working on my project using angular-cli. In one of my components in need to import the code of my HTML page by doing this: `this.document.body.innerHTML += this.get_template_skeleton.template_code2;` , once i change the code in need to catch a certain `<div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function selectDiv() {
     //create a new HTMLElement from nativeElement
   // var hElement: HTMLElement = this.elRef.nativeElement;

    //now you can simply get your elements with their class name
   var allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];

   var getSection = document.getElementById("main-wrapper").innerHTML;

    console.log(allDivs);
    console.log(getSection); // returning nothing
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="selectDiv()">select div</button>

   <div class="container"  id="main-wrapper">   
<p>
 Fetch me
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The demo below shows how to transfer [innerHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) from one element to another using both the [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) methods.

[Working JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p7czo8f4/)

HTML

```
<button onclick="selectDiv()">select div</button>

<div class="container" id="main-wrapper">
  <p>
    Fetch me
  </p>
</div>

<div id="containerDivByIdResults">

</div>

<div id="containerDivByClassResults">

</div>
```

Typescript

```
selectDiv = () => {
  document.getElementById("containerDivByIdResults").innerHTML = document.getElementById("main-wrapper").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("containerDivByClassResults").innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: error: Type 'string' cannot be converted to type 'HTML
Element'.

Comment: @JessicaStorm Remove the `<HTMLElement>` type assertion.

Comment: @JessicaStorm Looks like there are a couple errors in your TypeScript code. My latest answer simplifies with a working demo link to get you started :)

Comment: can you please help me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253152/html-button-stops-working-after-injecting-additonal-html-using-this-document-bo , i can explain my problem over chat or there as nobody is understanding the problem